# I want to write other languages code in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am working on building a website.
I made all things, but now I'm stuck in adding code to the website.
I want to put some codes inside the JSX component but it is having some problems with adding `{` `<<`these types of symbols.
Is there any way I can write the C++ code or C code inside the react element?

```js
import React from 'react'

const Template = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Template
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to place the code inside h1?

Comment: Hi Mohit, I understand you are new to Stack Overflow community, hence just a suggestion to do a bit of research before asking might help you and many other people save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The JSX won't appreciate the "{ <<", but if you want a quick in on this, you may try something like this -

```
const SomeCode = ()=><code>{`#include <stdio.h>;`}</code>
```

That might not be sufficient - you may need proper highlighting with specific programming language, formatting, etc. for what you might be building. But just for getting literals such as `<<` working with JSX - you may take the above example as base.

Answer (score -1):

In JSX, which is what react usees, brackets will be parsed.

Therefore, strings should be inside `` {`content`} ``, or you can define that code as a string, and place it inside jsx as below

```
const SomeComponent = ()=>{
  const codeSnippet = `{ << whatever code blahblah`

  return <div>
    {codeSnippet}
  </div>
}
```